# Margin , width fantasma (iframe do google)

Tags: jquery, html

Caros, olá. Estou desenvolvendo um site , porém existe uma margin ou width que não está declarado no site que está atrapalhando a sua visualização. Ao fazer um teste no inspecionar elemento me deparei com uns frames declarados pelo google e vi que são eles que estão fazendo essa margin. Segue exemplo do código descrito.

```
<iframe name="oauth2relay1380469440" id="oauth2relay1380469440" src="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/postmessageRelay?parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.LGFZ9cC0bWM.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMsrVkC5z6iTSQ0Ly8uCy_z20NJnw#rpctoken=722483838&amp;forcesecure=1" tabindex="-1" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: -100px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu problema. Poste uma imagem da tela, o elemente ao qual esse iframe está inserido... algo que se possa analisar. Esse iframe acrescenta algo ao seu layout? Se não, tente resolver adicionando o atributo`style="display:none;"` ao elemento iframe, pois alguns iframes do google apenas devem estar na página, não necessariamente visíveis.

Comment: Está um link de exemplo :  http://imgur.com/BktXNyf. 
Aparece esse código no final do body em que não declarei no código inicial. Quando eu deleto pelo inspecionar elemento no google, apaga, mas tenho que encontrar onde é declarado a função para conseguir apagar.

Comment: Você está usando alguma plataforma como joomla, wordpress, magento...?

Comment: Não, desenvolvi normalmente, sem uso de nenhum CMS

Comment: Você adicionou algum código de terceiros? Veja se minha reposta abaixo resolve.

Comment: Uso, um plugin chamado youmax.js que importa os vídeos do youtube para ser mostradosno meu site. Ele que está gerando esse código de autenticação. Quero ver como retirar as  propriedades css dele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu resolvi esse problema ao colocar no css a propriedade do html para "overflow-x :  hidden;"  ignorando tudo que possa vazar.

Exemplo :

html {

width:100%;

overflow-x: hidden;

}

Answer (score 0):

Se você está usando algum CMS, plataforma e-commerce ou algo do tipo, então em algum lugar este código está sendo gerado, e as vezes é complicado descobrir onde.

Tente adicionar o bloco abaixo em seu documento:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body iframe').css('margin', '0px');
  $('body iframe').css('padding', '0px');
  $('body iframe').css('width', '0px');
  $('body .main').next().css('margin', '0px');
  $('body .main').next().css('width', '0px');
  $('body .main').next().css('padding', '0px');
});
</script>
```

Este código irá apenas remover as margens e largura do código, mas ele ainda será gerado.

Comment: Funcionou, mas infelizmente afetou o layout, retirando a barra de rolagem para as outras sessões do site, então se tornou inviável

Comment: Alterei o bloco. Verifique a resposta novamente e tente com esse novo bloco!

Comment: Eu descobri qual jquery estava surgindo essa margin. É um plugin chamando youmax.js que usa autenticação do youtube(google) surgindo o campo "oauth2relay408099084".